# Can't get innertext from object

Tags: vba, web-scraping, scripting

I am using below code, to retrive the total number of products on a given page, but get a runt-time error 428 on gg = ohtml.innertext

```
Sub testp()

numpage = GetNumberofPages("https://sheetmaterialswholesale.co.uk/sheet-materials/")
End Sub


Function GetNumberofPages(numpage As String)



    Set xhr = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    With xhr
        .Open "GET", numpage, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
         html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    Dim ohtml As Object
 
    Set ohtml = html.querySelectorAll(".noOfProducts")
 
  Dim gg As String
  
  gg = ohtml.innerText
 gg = Replace(gg, ",", "")
 

    
nmpage = Round(Val(gg) / 36, 0) + 1

'nmpage = Val(Mid(Text, aa + 66, 5))

GetNumberofPages = nmpage

End Function
```

Any tips how to solve this?

Comment: `ohtml(0).innerText` ?

Answer (score 1):

The class you are using doesn't exist on the page and querySelectorAll returns a nodeList which doesn't have a .innerText property.

You can retrieve the page specific product count with the following css selector list which identifies the li elements associated with each product. Take the .Length property of the returned nodeList to get the number of products on the page

```
Debug.Print oHtml.querySelectorAll(".products li.product").Length
```

If you actually want the number of pages, calculated using the total product results count, then you can extract this total result count, as shown below, and use the results per page count as the denominator in the page count calculation.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub testp()

    MsgBox GetNumberOfPages("https://sheetmaterialswholesale.co.uk/sheet-materials/")

End Sub

Public Function GetNumberOfPages(ByVal numpage As String) As Long
    Dim xhr As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    Set xhr = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    With xhr
        .Open "GET", numpage, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    'Dim ohtml As Object
    Dim ohtml As MSHTML.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection
    
    Set ohtml = html.querySelectorAll(".products li.product")
 
    Dim numProductsPerPage As Long, numProducts As Long, numPages As Long
     
    numProductsPerPage = ohtml.Length            'assuming page you pass into function is representative
    numProducts = CInt(html.querySelector(".cat-parent .count").innerText)
    numPages = WorksheetFunction.Ceiling_Math(numProducts / numProductsPerPage)
     
    GetNumberOfPages = numPages

End Function
```